# Making custom email client in android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I recently started my first app for college, and as part of my app I need to do a custom email client. Meaning there's a login activity where the user can type in his/her gmail address and password to connect to the account. (security risks not important here, this app would not be uploaded to the store, "inside" usage only).

After connecting this would take us to the next activity where the user could chose between send a new email, fetch inbox messages or fetch sent messages.(another 3 activity later) All of these functionalities have guides on how to do them (on stackoverflow, tutorialspoint, etc, although a lot of them not for android specifically or not using AsyncTask), I know i checked a lot of them, but all of these assume we want these from the activity where we give address and password. My first goal would be to just connect to the user's account and I can't seem to achive it. I made this so far:

**Email_LoginActivity.java**:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
}


public void connectToTheServer() {
    if (isOnline()) {
        if (usernameInput.getText().toString().isEmpty() || passwordInput.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter both username and password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {

            class LoginToEmailAccount extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
//I made this class here so I can get a dialogbox to the activity until the user waits.
                ProgressDialog progress;
                private Folder inbox;
                private Folder sent;
                public static final String INBOX_STRING = "INBOX";
                public static final String SENT_ITEMS_STRING = "MMS_Sent";

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(Email_LoginActivity.this, null, "Login in progress, please wait.", true);
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    final String username = args[0];
                    final String password = args[1];

                    String host = "pop.gmail.com";

                    Properties properties = new Properties();
                    properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", host);
                    properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
                    properties.put("mail.pop3s.starttls.enable", "true");

                    // Setup authentication, get session
                    Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,
                            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                                            username, password);
                                }
                            });

                    try {

                        // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
                        Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
                        store.connect();

                        //should i create the folders here too?
                        inbox = store.getFolder(INBOX_STRING);
                        sent = store.getFolder(SENT_ITEMS_STRING);

                        //create
                        inbox.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
                        sent.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);


                        // open folders
                        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                        sent.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                        if(store.isConnected()){
                            Log.i("mytag", "connected");
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.i("mytag", "not connected)");
                        }

                    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("mytag", "sad times");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    return "Login complete";

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    progress.dismiss();
                }


            }
            new LoginToEmailAccount().execute(usernameInput.getText().toString(), passwordInput.getText().toString());
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please make sure you have internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void startEmailMainActivity(View view) {
    connectToTheServer(); //here we need a condition to check if the connection was successful before calling the next activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Email_MainActivity.class); //probably gonna need some extra intent info too
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

(usernameInput and passwordInput is the 2 EditText view where the user gives the info to us, declared in onCreate)

**AndroidManifest.xml has these**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I checked in debug mode and I get a MessagingException after the sent.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); line. My main idea was to follow [this guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_authentication.htm) just to connect to the account. By the way for testing I made [this guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_gmail_smtp_server.htm) working with the help of AsyncTask, it's just has the same problem that I want to do the sending email part on a different activity where I don't have to give the username and password again.

What should I do differently? Sorry if the question is too broad, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `his/her gmail address`. You mean `email address`?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, that POP3 access is enabled in the account settings.
Login to your account and enable POP3.
You also need to enable "less secure apps" (third party apps) in the Gmail settings.

Comment: POP3 was enabled by default and I enabled less secure apps when I tested another app a week before this. I updated my post though, I get the exception after sent.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Comment: Post your exception log

Comment: I have this now:
} catch (MessagingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            e.getMessage();
                            Log.i("mytag", "sad times :(");
In debug the "sad times" log shows even though the app frozes at e.getMessage(); (I got the "connected" log too after I moved it up after the store.connect line)

Comment: Please post the actual [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).